# How to assign php while loop into smarty to get required result

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

i want to show featured ads in slider problem is there is two table have to use to get ads. First one is class_ads that have all info of ad like title, description, price etc and second table is class_ads_pictures from where i have to match id of each ad and get the name of folder and picture name from table ....

Please review my poor logic and teach me

```
  <?php

    require_once "include/include.php";

    global $db;
    global $lng;
    $smarty = new Smarty;
    $smarty = common($smarty);


    $featured_ads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_ads where active=1 and featured=1 limit 50"); 
    while ($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($featured_ads)) { 
        $ad_id      = $temp['id'];
        $ad_title   = $temp['title'];

        //check for image if featured ad have image (Need to fetch only single image)
        $featured_ads_images = mysql_query("select from class_ads_pictures where ad_id=$ad_id order by order_no"); 
        $img = mysql_fetch_array($featured_ads_images);
        $img_id         = $img['id'];
        $ad_img         = $img['picture'];
        $img_folder     = $img['folder'];


        // Problem is how to assign and what have to assign, to get display in html file ...
    } 

    $smarty->assign('what', $what);

    $db->close();
    if($db->error!='') { $db_error = $db->getError(); $smarty->assign('db_error',$db_error); }

    $smarty->display('header_featured.html');
    close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should work. However you should not use mysql but PDO or mysqli because mysql is deprecated.

```
<?php

require_once "include/include.php";

global $db;
global $lng;
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty = common($smarty);


$ads = array();

$featured_ads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_ads where active=1 and featured=1 limit 50"); 
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured_ads)) { 
    $record = array();
    $record['ad_id']      = $temp['id'];
    $record['ad_title']   = $temp['title'];

    //check for image if featured ad have image (Need to fetch only single image)
    $featured_ads_images = mysql_query("select * from class_ads_pictures where ad_id={$record['ad_id']} order by order_no"); 
    $img = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured_ads_images);
    $record['img_id']         = $img['id'];
    $record['ad_img']         = $img['picture'];
    $record['img_folder']     = $img['folder'];

    $ads[] = $record;
} 

$smarty->assign('ads', $ads);

$db->close();
if($db->error!='') { $db_error = $db->getError(); $smarty->assign('db_error',$db_error); }

$smarty->display('header_featured.html');
close();
?>
```

In Smarty you can simple use it:

```
 {foreach item=item  from=$ads} 
  {$item.ad_id}
  {$item.ad_title}
  {$item.img_id}
  {$item.ad_img}
  {$item.img_folder}
 {/foreach}
```

Comment: So .. what i will write in smarty file .. Mean how i will receive record in smarty ..
please can you write the small code ...?

I will thankful for this act of kindness ...

Comment: I've added to answer how to use it in Smarty

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource on line 21 ...  $img = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured_ads_images);

Comment: I've fixed some code in my anwer, however there were errors in your queries in question and I haven't checked them just showed you how to assign data to Smarty

Comment: I added the file into my website header {include file="header_featured.html"}

It is not displaying any thing ...
But if write the url in browser with its .php file name like www.domain.com/header_featured.php   it shows results

what is the problem ...?

Comment: I don't know. You have to create new question with explaining your problem and files in details